# Loading content into div with Ajax ... How do I target the same div with the new page loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, hyperlink

I'm loading a php page into a div using the following:

```
<li><a href="content1.php" data-target="#right_section">Some Content</a></li>

$('[data-target]').click( function (e) {
var target = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
target.load($(this).attr('href'));
e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
});

<div id="right_section"></div>
```

This works perfectly fine.... however:

I want to load another page into that same div, but the link is in content1.php . I basically want it to overwrite itself with another page when a link is clicked.

Thoughts ?

Comment: SO you want to bind another link in the content loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's `.on` event handler to bind the click event.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

In your case it would look like:

**Main Page:**

```
<li><a href="content1.php" class="load-external" data-target="#right_section">Some Content</a></li>
<div id="right_section"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()){
    $('body').on('click', 'a.load-external', function(e){
        var target = $( $(this).attr('data-target') );
        target.load( $(this).attr('href') );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

**content1.php**

```
<li><a href="content2.php" class="load-external" data-target="#right_section">Some Content 2</a></li>
```

What this would do is bind the click event on all `a.someclass` elements inside `body` and that includes dynamically created elements.

Btw, I added the `.someclass` so that it will not bind to all `a` elements but only to specific `a` elements that you want to load a content from.

Comment: Ok, got it working fine ... there was an extra pair of brackets ... )}; ... in your post above. the code on fiddle worked for me. Thanks very much for this.

Comment: How would I also make this work from a form submit on content1.php ? <form action="report_output.php" method="get" name="graphIt" class="load-external" data-target="#right_section"> .... doesn't appear to want to work the same. (ps, I'm reading on answers, not just asking here without trying to resolve)

Comment: What happens after the submit? Because this will only work if your submitting via ajax, or else you'll be refreshing the whole page after submit.

Comment: Bumped into another small issue. When I click on the link and load Content1.php into right_section, all is fine. but on content1.php I have a link to the same content1.php but with some parameters. e.g.:       <A HREF="content1.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>&group=<?php echo $group; ?>&year=2014" class="load-external" data-target="#right_section">2014</A> .    ... this link does nothing at all. I cannot get it to load over top of itself with different data based on the url parameters... thoughts ? I know the link works if I remove the class and target, but I need to load it in place over itself

Comment: Try opening the generated link `content1.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>&group=<?php echo $group; ?>&year=2014` on a browser to check if it really works. There shouldn't be an issue here because javascript can only load the compiled html.

Comment: the links work fine if I load them directly, or remove the class and target

Comment: any further thoughts ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm absolutely stumped .... I have a lot of database work going on is this page to build a table.. might be related or not. I've about exhausted all I can think of at this point. I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: Try checking for javascript errors on the browser's console. Because as you said, when you load the page independently, the parameters work so definitely there's no db problem.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: M&group=narmo&archived=yes        So the M at the start of that query string would actually be passed in its entirety like this: name=Bob M&group=narmo&archived=yes .... Do you think the space between Bob and the M are causing this ?

Comment: Eureka ... it was the space in the name that was causing the grief. So my new link is: <a href="individual_report.php?name=<?php echo $escapedName; ?>&group=<?php echo $group; ?>&year=2015" class="load-external" data-target="#right_section"> ... in escaped name I added %20 in place of the space. Who would have thunk :) Thanks again DigitalDouble